# Selecting CDATA value of XML tag with PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, cdata

I'm pretty new to PowerShell and I'm struggling to read this XML data. The XML looks something like this:

**XML**

```
<RESULTS>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR1"><![CDATA[123456ABCDEF]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR2"><![CDATA[0.0.0.0]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR3"><![CDATA[Hello World]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR4"><![CDATA[Lorem ipsum]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR5"><![CDATA[This is some text]]></COLUMN>
    </ROW>
</RESULTS>
```

This is what my PowerShell looks like so far:

**PowerShell**

```
$xmlpath = 'Path\To\XML\File.xml'

$xmldata = [xml](Get-Content $xmlpath)

$xmldata.RESULTS.ROW.COLUMN | Select | Where-Object {$_.NAME -eq "ATTR3"}
```

And this is the result:

**Result**

```
ATTR3 Hello World
```

I would like to *just retrieve* "Hello World," but my script is also retrieving the attribute name (ATTR3). What am I missing?

**Example of desired result**

```
Hello World
```

Comment: for example `$xml.RESULTS.ROW.COLUMN.Where{ $_.Name -eq 'attr3' }.'#cdata-section'`

Comment: I tried your line in many different ways and that doesn't seem to do the trick. I end up getting the following error:

**PowerShell**
`$xmldata.RESULTS.ROW.COLUMN | Where {$_.NAME -eq "ATTR3"}.'#cdata-section'`

**Error**
`Where-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FilterScript' because it is null.`

Comment: Well you are using `where-object` there, my example shows the use of `.where` method

Comment: Oh, my apologies. Yeah, that worked. You should write it as an answer, so I can checkmark it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the community's reference, Santiago Squarzon's solution is provided below:

**Solution**

```
$xmldata.RESULTS.ROW.COLUMN.Where{ $_.NAME -eq "ATTR3"}.'#cdata-section'
```